# Finding average value of three weekdays, broken down on hours

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, logic

I have an origin-destination table like this in Bigquery with weekday, date, UTC time/hour and count of trips:

```
  Origin  Destination   Day     Date    Time Count

NY Station  Downtown    Mon  02.09.2019  15  12
NY Station  Downtown    Mon  02.09.2019  16  10
City libry  Eastside    Mon  02.09.2019  17  10
NY Station  Downtown    Tue  03.09.2019  15  8
NY Station  Downtown    Tue  03.09.2019  16  5
City libry  Eastside    Tue  03.09.2019  17  5
NY Station  Downtown    Wed  04.09.2019  15  8
NY Station  Downtown    Wed  04.09.2019  16  10
City libry  Eastside    Wed  04.09.2019  17  11
```

I wish to get the average *Count* for

- each origin-destination pair (*NY Station-Downtown* and *City libry-Eastside*)
- the average of Monday-Wednesday  at each given time

The output should then be something like

```
Origin    Destination   Avg_Day  Period                    Time Avg_Count

NY Station  Downtown    Mon-Wed  Week1 (02.09.19-04.09.19)  15  9,33
NY Station  Downtown    Mon-Wed  Week1 (02.09.19-04.09.19)  16  8,33
City libry  Eastside    Mon-Wed  Week1 (02.09.19-04.09.19)  17  8,67
```

Ignore the *Avg_day* and *Period* columns as its just for help/showing for which days and dates i wish to achieve the average for. In other words the aim is to have an idea of the average counts for each origin-destination pair on a normal weekday (in this case defined as mon-wed) on certain hours of the day. The average count of for example the time 15 for NY Station-Downtown pair is 9,33, calculated by taking the average of the count for 15 o'clock at Monday, at Tuesday and at Wednesday (that is the average of 12, 8 and 8).

I have tried variants of CASE and WHERE SQL queries, but not even close to grasping the logic on how to make the query for this so no point in posting any query. Possibly have to create a temporary table also. Can anyone help me? it is HUGELY appreciated

Comment: This looks like a simple aggregation query.  What issues are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select
  Origin, 
  Destination, 
  'Mon-Wed' AS Avg_Day,
  FORMAT('Week%i (%s-%s)', week, min_date, max_date) AS Period,
  Time,
  Avg_Count
from (
  SELECT 
    Origin, 
    Destination, 
    'Mon-Wed' AS Avg_Day,
    EXTRACT(WEEK FROM PARSE_DATE('%d.%m.%Y', date)) week, 
    MIN(date) AS min_date, 
    MAX(date) AS max_date,
    Time,
    ROUND(AVG(count), 2) AS Avg_Count
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE day IN ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed')
  GROUP BY Origin, Destination, Time, week 
)
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row Origin      Destination Avg_Day Period                          Time    Avg_Count    
1   NY Station  Downtown    Mon-Wed Week35 (02.09.2019-04.09.2019)  15      9.33     
2   NY Station  Downtown    Mon-Wed Week35 (02.09.2019-04.09.2019)  16      8.33     
3   City libry  Eastside    Mon-Wed Week35 (02.09.2019-04.09.2019)  17      8.67
```